# No boot menu after xubuntu install

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 14.10

Hello I am trying to install xubuntu 14.10 Ive tried also ubuntu,kubuntu... And I always get to this blinking cursor and no boot menu after installing it.No matter if I am trying ubuntu,xubuntu always I am ending with the sam problem.I will be very thankfull if someone know how to make it work.I am new to Linux and I couldnt find any solution on google.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that directly after powering on your pc nothing happens, it seems like GRUB is not loading.

Try re-installing GRUB from a Live CD/USB.
Detailed instructions can be found here: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Answer (score 0):

Graphics card could be causing the problem. If it's ATI or Nvidia you can use one of the nomodeset boot options. You can look them up, they might vary from computer to computer, or by OS.

Basicly you would type a command before you install xubuntu with the live cd. With that you can bypass what's causing the error just enough for you to update drivers or what have you. If your computer is 64 bit and you installed 64bit xubuntu, try 32 bit instead it might work for you.